# how to get the full data from nvarchar?

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2000

fetching a data from sql server 2000 
type nvarchar with length 1500

when i try to print it using print_r or echo in php
the message gets cut off to 255 char, there is no error, and
in database the message is there, but i cant fetch them all

how do i fix this ?

example field message

i just use simple fetch function it work, just cant get the full data

```
$result = "some query here"
while($line = $VinDB->fetch_array($result)){

if (@$line["message"] != null)
{echo @$line["message"];}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the mssql extension, you have to consider either to change the original type of the column to TEXT/NTEXT, or to cast it to TEXT/NTEXT.

There is a bug in the old extension:

*Note: Note to Windows Users:
Due to a limitation in the underlying API used by PHP (MS DBLib C API), the length of VARCHAR fields is limited to 255. If you need to store more data, use a TEXT field instead.*

From: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-field-length.php

Comment: ya i tried, the nvarchar didnt work, so i change it to text worked just fine

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try setting the data type to text or ntext. It might be an issue regarding the max character limit on nvarchar.